# What's the difference between tethering and hitching an animal?

Tags: differences, comparisons

> Hitching, tethering, picketing, or securing any pack or saddle stock within 200 feet slope distance of any permanent lake, stream, spring, pond. or shelter.

Doesn't both mean tying an animal to a fixture?

Comment: ***To hitch :***
 to fasten or tie, especially temporarily, by means of a hook, rope, strap, etc.;  ***tether:*** 
Steve hitched the horse to one of the posts. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hitched+up

Comment: They just wanted to cover all the bases, so no one would claim "My horse wasn't hitched, he was tethered!"  But generally "tether" would imply being on a longer rope, to allow the animal to roam a little.

Comment: @Josh61, you comment does not make sense.  Please revise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'hitching'

You might temporarily hitch a horse to a rail. The animal's movement is fairly restricted.

[image]

'tether'

A grazing animal such as a goat (or indeed a horse) can be tethered to a peg in the ground so that it is free to graze. This is done for an indefinite amount of time.

[image]